# .update is not being detected as a function in my game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my code, Im a student and Im working on this project. My goal is to get the paddle moving with the mouse up& down with the mouse. I dont understand why its not working, if someone could please help me link the mouse and the paddle to go up & down and tell me what i did wrong, that would be amazing :)

```js
(function() {
  var htmlCanvas = document.getElementById('area'),
    context = htmlCanvas.getContext('2d');
  initialize();

  function initialize() {

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    resizeCanvas();
  }


  function redraw() {
    context.strokeStyle = 'solid black';
    context.lineWidth = '1';
    context.strokeRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }


  function resizeCanvas() {
    htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    redraw();
  }
})();

//Javascript Document no work? Just do it here and ask mark later.

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

//⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤Game Pieces!⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤⏤

// Paddle


//Events - Mouse Tracking!

var mouse = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
}
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  mouse.x = event.x;
  mouse.y = event.y;

})

function Paddle(x, y, width, height, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width
  this.height = height
  this.color = color

  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.fillStyle = " #333333"
    c.fillRect(25, 275, 50, 300);
    c.stroke();
  }
};

update() {
  paddle.x = mouse.x
  this.draw();
};


var paddle = new Paddle(25, 275, 50, 300);



//  Ball 
var x = 945;
var y = 415
var dx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 7;
var dy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 7;
var radius = 25

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  c.canvas.width = c.canvas.width;
  c.beginPath();
  paddle.update(); //So it doesn't get erased?
  c.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  c.stroke();
  c.closepath;

  if (x + radius > innerWidth || x - radius < 0 - radius - radius) {
    dx = -dx
  }

  if (y + radius > innerHeight || y - radius < 0) {
    dy = -dy;
  }
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}


render();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='area' style='position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;'>
  
    </canvas>
```

Comment: Your code gives console errors. Fix them.

Comment: `update() {
  paddle.x = mouse.x
  this.draw();
};` is a problem

Comment: Creating a snippet that has other errors besides the one you are asking about doesn't help. If you are really not able to create a runnable snippet to demonstrate your problem, just post the code in the non-runnable format. You are also not explaining what is the exact error you're getting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `update()` is not a method of the `Paddle` object.

Answer (score 0):

`update` needs to be in the `Paddle` prototype so you can use `paddle.update()`, and it should assign to `this.x` rather than hard-coding the global variable `paddle`. You shoiuld also do the same thing with the `draw` method; there's no need to attach it to each object.

```
function Paddle(x, y, width, height, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width
  this.height = height
  this.color = color

};

Paddle.prototype.draw = function() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.fillStyle = " #333333"
  c.fillRect(25, 275, 50, 300);
  c.stroke();
}

Paddle.prototype.update = function() {
  this.x = mouse.x
  this.draw();
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! However, how would I do the same with the ball

Comment: You'd need to write a `function Ball(...)` and similar methods. You might want to learn about ES6 classes, they simplify this.